# How do I learn about PowerBI Datamarts?

Tags: powerbi

I logged into my PowerBI online application (Pro license) and noticed a new 'Datamart(Preview)' feature in my workspace. I spent some time looking up documentation and tutorials to learn more about what this is all about, but I cannot find anything!

Can anyone point me in the right direction where I can learn more about this feature?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Preview means that it is still under development and you cant find documentation. Wait for Announcing general availability.

Comment: @msta42a I did not know that. Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is typical that documentation will not be available for preview features